# Request for dynamic range solution when deleting based on a filter

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently working on making a macro to automate some work I have to do in Excel on a daily basis. However, since this is my first encounter with Visual Basic and Macros in Excel in general, I'm struggling to implement dynamic range selection based on filter results.

Basically, the idea is that I delete a range of rows after applying a filter on a header. Since this range of rows changes, I need the code to dynamically pick the range based on the filter result. To give a practical example, this is one filter I'm applying:

```
Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$AQ" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="="
Rows("34:34").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$AQ" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=10
Columns("J:J").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

The issue lies with "Rows("34:34").Select", since these rows would change from day to day.

I've done some reading around the website, and I have tried several suggestions involving the SpecialCell function, however, these aren't currently working for me (I'm likely doing something wrong).

I imagine there to be a simple solution to this, so I'm hoping one of you would point me in the right direction? It would be help me a lot.

I hope I've managed to make some sense.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: so, the main idea is to apply filter and delete all rows than mathes the filter?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In my example I'm filtering out blanks from forecast data, but I also have cases where I'm filtering based on product seasonality etc etc. I always apply the filter on the field header too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("A4:AQ" & lastrow)
    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="="
    'get all rows except header. Only visible rows would be deleted
    .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    .AutoFilter Field:=10
End With
```

Comment: To my knowledge, that worked perfectly! However, one question: when I check the filter in the header, it shows that there are "blanks". When I tick this, I just get an empty selection. I imagine this is related to the deletion? (It's not actually a problem, I just want to make sure that I'm not deleting too much/too little). Thanks again, it's very much appreciated.

I had actually previously tried a similar code, but without the "with'. I'll have to google the significance of this inclusion since it means very little to me. Either way, you've been a gem.

Comment: it's "fantom" blanks after deletion, don't worry, this code deletes exactly rows you need to delete:)